# AngularJS uses eval in chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, eval

The lates AngularJS (1.3 beta 19) uses `eval`. This is prohibited in chrome extionsion.

How to fix the issue **[without allowing evals](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval)**?

Error message:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
>   not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Stack trace:

```
angular.js:1011
csp angular.js:1011
(anonymous function) angular.js:23556
```

UPDATE: See documentation of `ng-csp` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

OUTDATED: It looks like AngularJS fails to detect CSP in chrome extension. Use explicit `ng-csp`. Link to the AngularJS issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8777

Comment: Well if Angular now uses eval, I don't see how you would be able to use it without explicitly allowing eval calls in your extension configuration?

Comment: Since it's a beta release, it's quite possible that this is a bug.

Comment: @Xan If this is bug then it should be fixed. If it is fundamental AngularJS approach then it should be stated.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet May be some standard workaround exists. If you and me do not know this does not mean nobody knows.

Comment: Is this something you can bisect? Did your code work with a previous version?

Comment: @DmitryKaigorodov: You are right. Open an issue on GitHub and see if the Angular guys have the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) that Dmitry linked:

> Angular tries to autodetect if CSP is active and automatically turn on
>   the CSP-safe mode. This autodetection however triggers a CSP error to
>   be logged in the console:
>
> > *Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
> >     not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
> >     Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src' was not
> >     explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*
>
> This error is harmless but annoying. To prevent the error from showing
>   up, put the [`ngCsp` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) on the root element of the application
>   or on the `angular.js` script tag, whichever appears first in the html
>   document.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found: enforcing CSP mode by adding `ng-csp` on an element of document.

See documentation of `ng-csp` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp