# Angular expression evaluates in Chrome extension but not in Edge extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a simple browser extension, using Angular (v1.6.3), but the Angular expression in the pop-up window of the browser extension is failing to evaluate in Edge, but it is in Chrome.

The Angular expression is simply `<div>{{2+2}}</div>`.

When I browse to a relevant website (as configured in the [manifest file](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/manifest.json), namely http://marketplace.visualstudio.com, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com or http://www.bbc.com, and click the extension button, Chrome evaluates the html output to "4", but Edge evaluates the html output to "{{2+2}}".

Chrome example

[image: Chrome as a browser extension]

Edge example

[image: Edge as a browser extension]

I believe the html and angular interaction itself is fundamentally sound, because when I browse directly to the [pop up page](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/popup.html), using a URL such as `file:///C:/temp/app/popup.html`, both Chrome and Edge correctly evaluate the expression `{{2+2}}` to "4".

Chrome example when brosing directly to [popup.html](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/popup.html)

[image: Chrome direct browse to popup.html]

Edge example when browsing directly to [popup.html](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/popup.html)

[image: Edge direct browse to popup.html]

To summarize, it is only as an Edge extension that the expression evaluation fails; as a Chrome extension or with direct browsing in both Edge and Chrome it works.

Thirty second video demo on You Tube:
[image: YouTube demo]

I have placed a full version of the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge) but code is quite simple and consists of the following:

A [popup.html](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/popup.html) file page for the pop-up window, which contains the Angular expression:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
   <div>{{2+2}}</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

An [app.js](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js) file to define the angular module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

A [contentscript.js](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/scripts/contentscript.js) that tells the website to open the pop-up:

```
// Set the window object for multiple browser compatibility
window.browser = (function () {
return window.msBrowser ||
  window.browser ||
  window.chrome;
})();

window.browser.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "openPopUp" });
```

A [background.js](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/scripts/background.js) script that actually opens the [popup.html](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/popup.html) file:

```
// Set the window object for multiple browser compatibility
window.browser = (function () {
return window.msBrowser ||
  window.browser ||
  window.chrome;
})();

window.browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.action == "openPopUp") {
            window.browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true },
                function (tabs) {
                    window.browser.pageAction.show(tabs[0].id);
                });
        }
    });
```

And finally a [manifest.json](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksInChromeNotInEdge/blob/master/app/manifest.json) file that wires everything up together, which both browsers understand:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "BrowserExtensionUsingAngularWorksChromeNotEdge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Greg Trevellick",
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon_19x19.png"
    },
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "scripts/background.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/*",
        "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/*",
        "http://www.bbc.co.uk/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/contentscript.js",
        "scripts/angular.min.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/",
    "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/",
    "http://www.bbc.co.uk/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

For what its worth, some instructions on getting started with Chrome extensions can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) and for Edge [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Debugging-Microsoft-Edge-Extensions).

Comment: It's not just an expression that is not evaluated. It's Angular app that is not bootstrapped. If it fails to bootstrap, there should be an error. What does error message say?

Comment: Do you mean an error in the console ? I don't recall seeing any errors in the console.

Comment: There always should be an error if there's script error (and in your case it does). This becomes total guesswork if there's no error message. I don't do extension development in Edge, but there may be additional steps to display errors from extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently AngularJS will not bootstrap for the Edge extension protocol. I've submitted a [PR on GitHub to address this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/16031). If you make [this change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/16031/files) in the `angular.js` file you will see it start working.

You can also [bootstrap manually](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you kspearrin ! I made the simple change you suggested and hey presto the angular expression now resolves to "4" not "{{2+2}}" when using Edge :-)

Answer (score 2):

`unsafe-eval` is not supported in Microsoft Edge extensions now, you may want to use some workarounds mentioned in this similar question [AngularJS uses eval in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503213/angularjs-uses-eval-in-chrome-extension)

From [Supported manifest keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-manifest-keys)

> Microsoft Edge extensions currently only support [Default Policy Restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Default_content_security_policy): `script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'`

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried without the "unsafe-eval" and even with an ng-csp attribute but it makes no difference. It's as if the angular controller has been found, but I'm running angular itself locally, not from a CDN.