# Angular 2 Edge extension not loading

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I want to build a Extension for Edge with Angular 2. After building the app and change the Manifest.json with Microsoft Edge Extension Toolkit i upload the app in Edge. 
If i want to use the Extension the app doesn´t load the components.

[image: Extension Popup]

My Manifest.json:

```html
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Addon",
"short_name": "Addon",
"description": "Addon",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "asd",
"icons": {
    "1": "favicon.ico"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Open a new tab to view your bookmarks.",
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "1": "favicon.ico"
    }
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "fontSettings"
],
"background": {
    "page": "index.html",
    "persistent": false
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"-ms-preload": {
    "backgroundScript": "backgroundScriptsAPIBridge.js",
    "contentScript": "contentScriptsAPIBridge.js"
}
}
```

Is there any unsopported or missing manifest key?

Comment: I'd be guessing it's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775016/angular-expression-evaluates-in-chrome-extension-but-not-in-edge-extension - `content_security_policy` is ignored, and in particular `unsafe-eval` is unsupported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular expression evaluates in Chrome extension but not in Edge extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775016/angular-expression-evaluates-in-chrome-extension-but-not-in-edge-extension)